# insert lots of data row by row with relationship check and possible bad data

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, winforms, entity-framework

I have read through many articles and questions here similar to this but havnt found anything close enought.

I have 40,000 rows in a 10 column excel file.
The data in this is hand typed from paper.

There are two main numbers, MO & Order, in the file I need to check first.
Since these are hand typed they can be wrong.

I have 2 tables
MO Table

```
moID     MO       Order
3409    87234    23845
3410    84562    21342
etc... (38k rows)
```

and

```
printID   moID   user   date   printer
5         3409   Brad   01/24  printer1
34        3409   Brad   01/30  printer1
40        3410   Joe    01/31  printer1
etc... (9k ish and growing)
```

PROCESS:

I loop through each row in my c# app, query to get the moID.  then query to see if the job already exists, then do an Insert.  If moID cannot be found I query to log possible MO & Order combinations to let them fix the file later.

LINK QUERYS:

```
curMOID = dbReports.MoNumbers.Where(r => r.moNumber == moNum && r.moOrder == orderNum).Select(c => c.id_moNumber).FirstOrDefault();
var printJobs = dbReports.PaperPrints.Where(q => q.id_moNumber == curMOID && q.printDate == printDate && q.rowExcelFile == curRow);
if (printJobs.Where(q => q.printSize == null).Count() == 0)
```

QUESTION:

my moID query takes ~250ms (application time, direct query is ~.075ms).  Same with the already exists and list of options.  So each row is taking about .5 seconds to run through.  At 40k rows is taking 5+ hours.  I have to do this with a user daily.  Is there a better way to do this or some way to speed the query through application up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this is a painfull, a very painfull way to do it. There is a painless way that's faster and does not involve any coding.

**Step 1: Export file as CSV**

**Step 2: use [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)**
Use this to load the data into a dummy table

> The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a
>   table at a very high speed

**Step 3: Create destination table**

Make it exactly like the dummy table but make sure that you have a unique index on the columns that you don't want duplicated.

You can do this with the [CREATE TABLE LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html) statement

**Step 4: Select from temp into final**
yes, the syntax is

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO destination SELECT * FROM tmp_table
```

**Step 5: Use a [multi table delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) to clean up the tmp_table**

There you have a table with the rows that could not be imported. And you have done it with in a minute with zero lines of code

Comment: I have a table already so when you say create destination table, that would be my already created table.  And the dummy table should be a table like that table, correct?

Comment: yes, exactly. It would be to create a dummy like the real thing.

Comment: I created a MO & Order column on my temp table.  Then creating a query to grab the moIDs and update the records.  Then insert Ignore.  Is that the right way or possible to do a single moID check while inside the insert ingnore into.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your comment. Do you mean to say what was tried is different from what's described above

Comment: because my Excel has MONumber and OrderNumber but the table i put it to has a related moID.  I copied my print table structure.  Added a MO and Order column.  LOAD DATA INFILE (2.5 seconds :)  ).  now I am writing SQL to update moID on the table and then move that data to the real table.  The data will have some MOs missing or Orders missing and possible bad values here or there which I clean up a lot in code but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken your using `moID` as the unique key to determine if you should insert, so:

Your best bet would be to start batching the queries.

Take 5000 `moID` and query them first, then remove any that return from the 5000 you set aside, then do a bulk insert of what ever is left. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @e4c5.  Got me where I needed to go.  Want to give a clear picture of what I did.  This used to take 5+ HOURS and now takes 5 SECONDS.  I am still using a C# program to check the file, csv creation and sending it via LOAD DATA INFILE.

1) **Created a CSV with each row having the information across all tables.**

- Used EPPLUS to open the file.  check mandatory fields for the types I want and stopped if there was an error so the user will fix the required fields.

2) **Created a copy of the table i wanted to insert into**

- The new Table is called StagePrintJob

3) **Added columns for the values of MO and Order in my case.**

4) **Changed the moID field on the stage table to be default of 0**

5) **Used the LOAD DATA INFILE query**

- I truncate (clear) the table so I dont have to create it every time.  Just reuse.

  ```
          "TRUNCATE TABLE  `" + table + "`; " +

          string.Format("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{0}' INTO TABLE `" + table + "` ", csvFullName).Replace(@"\", @"\\") +
          "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " +
          "ENCLOSED BY '\"' " +
          "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' " +
          "ignore 1 lines " +
          "(@printFix, moClient, moNumber, moOrder, printComment, printPrinter, printStatus, printUser, printIssue, printSolution, printQty, rowExcelFile, excelFile) " +
          "SET printDate = STR_TO_DATE(@printFix, '%m/%d/%Y'); " +
          "Call PaperPrintProcedure('" + printFileName + "')";
  ```
- the SET printDate is a method to convert my date string to one that mySQL understands
- I used LOCAL on the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE so  I could use a file on my local PC and not have to send it to the mySQL server first.

6) **Created a stored Procedure (could just run the commands).  I made an update query checking my value against the table I wanted.**

```
        update StagePrint test inner join MoNumbers mo on test.moNumber = mo.moNumber && test.moOrder = mo.moOrder
        set test.id_moNumber = mo.id_moNumber;
```

7) **I insert the staged rows into my actual table as long as it has an id for the MO now.**

- I delete the rows that are the same as my file because there is no good ids in the excel file so this works for now.

  ```
      DELETE FROM  `PaperPrint` WHERE  `excelFile` =  printFileName;

      insert into PaperPrint(id_moNumber, printQty, printDate, printSize, printUser, printPrinter, printStatus, printIssue, printSolution, printComment, rowExcelFile, excelFile) 
      select id_moNumber, printQty, printDate, printSize, printUser, printPrinter, printStatus, printIssue, printSolution, printComment, rowExcelFile, excelFile from StagePrint 
      where StagePrint.id_moNumber <> 0;
  ```

8) **Query the StagedTable for any records where your `ID = 0` and either fix or delete them.**